# Racket interaction in DrRacket and on terminal

Tags: racket, raco

This program works fine in DrRacket :

```
(define (display-state input data)
  input)

(define (update-state input data) 
  data  )

(define (main input data)  
    (displayln (display-state input data))
    (main (read-line (current-input-port) 'any) (update-state input data)))

(main "" data)
```

It's the skeleton of a program that reads continually from a  terminal interaction and does something with the user's input and a data state.

However, on the terminal, using

```
raco exe prog.rkt
```

It terminates after the first input. Anyone know why? Is it a bug / feature of read-line or current-input-port ?

Comment: That program works fine when I either run `racket prog.rkt` or when I use `raco exe prog.rkt` `./prog`.

Comment: Although I noticed it prints out `#<eof>` and keeps going asking for more input even if I press ctrl-D. You should probably handle that case, since `read-line` returns either a string or eof.

Comment: For me, it terminates after I hit enter for the first time.

Comment: and it treats the output it prints as if they were an input to the terminal

Comment: eg. if I type in "blah" it finishes and then looks for a command on my system called "blah"

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, 14.04

Comment: Ah ... no ... I see what I did wrong

Answer (score 1):

OK. I see what I did wrong. (Stupid, but I'll leave this in case anyone else has the same problem)

I expected raco exe to be *running* the program. But actually it was just compiling it into the executable.

So I was just typing into what I thought was the input when actually I was typing into the window waiting for compilation to terminate.

Actually I needed to compile with

```
raco exe prog.rkt
```

and THEN run with

```
./prog
```

Doh!

Comment: Normally I run Racket programs using `racket`. If you `raco make` (directly or via `raco setup`), that generates `compiled/*` bytecode files. That's the slowest part. Thereafter `racket` has "nothing" to do and is quite fast. JIT from bytecode to native code is very fast, and happens at runtime regardless.  In other words `raco exe` is about deploying, making an executable to run on other computers. It's not the normal way people run locally.

Comment: Actually, @GregHendershott I'm looking into Racket precisely because I want a Lisp for writing small, stand-alone command-line tools which don't need the full environment installed.